# accessing the caller data type in a member function

Tags: c++

I want to do something like this code:

```
myType a;
a->foo();

void foo()
{
   cout << a->bar(); 
}
void bar()
{
   cout << a->bar2();
}
void bar2()
{
   cout << a->bar3();
}
```

In another word, when a member function is called, can we use the original caller?

Comment: to me it's not clear what you're actually asking - is foo supposed to be a method of the class `myType`? But then you could just use `this` to reference what I think you're referring to as "original caller" (the variable `a`).

Comment: Please clarify your code example. It wouldn't compile and it doesn't clearly state WHAT you actually want to do.

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do. Show us where "bar" is defined.

Comment: Your edit of the original post adds zero information. You are still not telling us which class each function belongs to. We are not magicians, you know. We cannot guess what you have in your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
cout << this->bar();
```

Or, more simply

```
cout << bar();
```

[This IBM C++ documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr035.htm) explains it pretty well. Have a look.

Comment: supposing `bar()` is a *method* of `myType`, as well as `foo()`; looking at the code it looks more like bar is a member *variable* of myType...

Comment: Is that valid for more than one level call?

Comment: @mahmood: what kind of level are you referring to? recursion level?

Comment: @nyarlathotep: I edited the original post, foo() and bar() are member function for myType

Comment: @nyarlathotep: yes please see the original post again

Comment: @mahmood: by "yes", are you referring to my recursion level question? I don't see any proper recursion in your question, though...? So the methods foo, bar and bar2 are all supposed to be members of myType? Then I would recommend for you to read up on how to define classes in c++

Comment: @nyarlathotep: please ignore the "yes". What I want is stated in the original post.

Comment: I don't think he wants the recursion stuff, I think he just wants to access a member in the object he created that's an instance of `myType`, which is what I'm saying in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you're probably trying to do is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class myType {
    void foo()
    {
       std::cout << bar(); 
    }
    void bar()
    {
       std::cout << bar2();
    }
    void bar2()
    {
       std::cout << bar3();
    }
};
```

... and in e.g. main method:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    myType a;
    a->foo();
}
```

Inside a class, you can refer to methods of the same class just by their name, and they will be called on the same object as the original method! If you want to highlight that you're referring to methods of the same object, use e.g. `this->bar()` instead of `bar()`; it is only *necessary* in cases where there are other names (e.g. method parameters) which would conceal the class members, but it *can* be used all the time.